# Array length in C language

Tags: c, arrays, function, parameters, c99

I am a previous C# programmer and there is something I can't understand regarding the C language. (Specifically, I am coding using the C99 Standard)

I was taught that there is no way to know the length of an array in C and that I need to send its length as a parameter to the function I am willing to use but why is that?
In C#, for example, we can type `array_name.length`.

Plus, in two dimensional arrays why do I have to specify the number of columns of the array? I mean why this work:

```c
void test1 (int arr[][m])
{
}
```

but this doesn't:

```c
void test2 (int arr[][])
{
}
```

Comment: "I need to send its length as a parameter to the function I am willing to use but why is that?" Because the language doesn't support the other way.

Comment: This is actually a good question - he's asking about the runtime environment difference and historical perspective, which is deeper than most folks go in thinking about a language.  He's not just saying "Why does C stink?"

Comment: You certainly can determine the length of an array: `sizeof array / sizeof array[0]`. The problem is C doesn't permit arrays as function parameters, and something that looks like a parameter of array type is really of pointer type. Strongly recommended reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com).

Answer (score 4):

> in C# for example we can type `array_name.length`

I do not use C#, but, if, in a subroutine you can get the length of an array created elsewhere, then information about that length had to be stored in memory and passed along with the array. Something had to put that length in memory, and, when the array was passed as an argument, something had to include information more than just the length of the array. So C# is using memory and computing time.

A consequence of this is you do not have direct control of the computer. You **cannot** write a simpler more efficient program as long as something is passing extra information. It is necessarily wasteful. That is fine as long as you are writing programs in situations where plenty of resources are available.

C does not make this extra effort. When an array is passed, only its location is passed, and that is all you need to access its elements. If a particular subroutine needs its length, you can pass that manually—it is your choice to do it when you need to, but you also have the option not to waste resources when you do not need them. You can write more efficient programs.

> in two dimensional arrays why do I have to specify the number of columns of the array?

If we know `arr` is an array of `int`, we know element `arr[0]` is at the start, `arr[1]` is right after that, `arr[2]` is after that, and so on. To use a one-dimensional array, the only thing we need to know is where it starts.

If we know `array` is a two-dimensional array of `int`, we know `a[0][0]` is at the start, `arr[0][1]` is after that, and so on, but we do not know where `arr[1][0]` is. It is after some number of elements `arr[0][i]`, but we do not know how many unless we know the second dimension. Therefore, in order to use a two-dimensional array, you **must** know the length of the second dimension. That is a logical requirement, not a choice.

### Supplement

Generally, a routine only needs to know **which** elements of an array it is supposed to use. It does not need to know how many elements there are in the array.

Situations in which a routine does not need to be given the length of an array include:

- To calculate the length of a string in a buffer, a routine (like `strlen`) only needs to examine each byte in the buffer until it finds a null byte. It does not need to know how big the entire buffer is. (Example: A program creates a buffer of 100 bytes. It reads bytes from the terminal until a new-line is found. The user types only 12 characters and then a new-line. The buffer is filled with 12 bytes and a null character. A subroutine examining the string only needs to work with 13 bytes, not 100.)
- A routine might work on a fixed number of elements. For example, a subroutine to help with numerical integration might take three function values at one time, fit a curve to them, and return the area under the curve. The main routine might have an entire array of function values, and it repeatedly calls the subroutine to evaluate different points in the array, passing the subroutine a pointer to the location to work on. In each call, the subroutine only needs to know there are three values for it at the given address. It does not need to know how many are in the full array.
- A routine might work on the same number of elements in multiple arrays. For example, a routine to perform a Discrete Fourier Transform might take a number of elements *N* to work on and four arrays: one for input of the real components, one for input of the imaginary components, one for output of the real components, and one for output of the imaginary components. For each of the arrays, the routine uses *N* elements. This number *N* only needs to be passed to the routine in one parameter. It would wasteful to store it in multiple locations, one for each array.

Another consideration is that sometimes we pass only part of an array to a routine. If I have some string in a buffer, I might want a subroutine to work on only part of that string, perhaps just one word in a command that has been parsed. To do this, I can pass just a pointer to the start of that word and the length of the word to work on. In this case, the subroutine not only does not need to know the length of the array, it does not even need to know where the array starts. It only needs to know what it is asked to work on. It would be wasteful to pass any other information.

Comment: Two additional questions: you mentioned "but you also have the option not to waste resources when you do not need them. You can write more efficient programs." but how could I need and use an array without knowing its dimensions? could you provide an example? also I think this isn't a heavy task at all since all we are saving is just a small number do we really need to be that efficient and why?

Comment: @Daniel98: You do not need to know the size of an array to use it. You only need to know how many elements (and which) you are supposed to use. If I ask a subroutine to sum three elements at a pointer I give it in the middle of an array, it only needs to know that it is supposed to use three elements. It does not ned to know how many elements are in the whole array.

Comment: @Daniel98: Yes, efficiency is important. Pointers are passed around in programs frequently. We make linked lists, we read text into buffers, we parse that text and pass pointers into it to subroutines, we construct trees and other data structures using pointers. Routines that work with graphical windows have pointers to windows and pointers to substructures within them, such as information about what buttons are there and which routines to call when buttons are clicked, pointers to what text is in them, and more. If every pointer had to include information about the size of the thing it…

Comment: … pointed to, the space used by many programs would increase by a considerable amount.

Answer (score 3):

In most programming languages, data types are *abstractions*: that is, if you ask for a list of numbers, it will create structures in memory for storing a list of numbers, and for keeping track of its capacity, how many elements are full, and perhaps whether the elements are "null" or contain values, etc.

C is a low-level language that doesn't deal in abstractions; it deals directly with physical memory. If you ask for space to put 5 integers, it allocates memory for 5 integers. You wanted it to keep track of the number "5" somewhere to remember that you allocated 5 integers? You didn't ask for that--you'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: Ritchie's Language deals with physical memory.  The language processed by the clang and gcc optimizers requires that programmers limit their use of memory to those that match the optimizers' abstrations, and will not behave reliably if programs need to do anything not accommodated by those abstractions.

Answer (score 0):

In C an array passed as a parameter to a function is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array. The size of the array is not implicitly passed to the function. You, the programmer, are responsible for passing the correct array size to your function.

```
int sum(int *num, size_t length)
{
   int total = 0;
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
      total += num[i];
   }
}
```

One of the problems with this approach is the parameter for the array is only assumed to point to an array. It could point to any int, whether or not that int is an element of an array. If this mistake is made a classical buffer overflow occurs.

Answer (score 0):

C is a Procedural language (and closer to assembler than most Procedural languages), not an Object Oriented language.  IOW, Algol (and C) came way before Smalltalk (and C#), and Smalltalk taught us some important lessons.

Sometimes you can use the following in C:

```
#define num_elements(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
```

...but when an array has been passed to a function, that often doesn't work anymore.

Another good way, that works in almost any situation in C, is to:

```
#define MY_ARRAY_ELEMENTS 1000
int a[MY_ARRAY_ELEMENTS];
foo(a, MY_ARRAY_ELEMENTS);
```

IOW, define a symbolic constant for the length of a particular array, and use that instead of hardcoding constants.

OO languages have metadata associated with objects anyway, so why not store a length in the metadata?  C doesn't do that sort of thing though - it was created in a time when bytes were precious, and metadata was seen as too much overhead.

And why do you have to partially define the size of an n dimensional array?  Because behind the scenes C is doing some math to multiply out where in memory a[x][y] exists, and again, it's not storing metadata to help you keep track of those dimensions.

Consider that Pascal, another Procedural language, made the array dimensions part of an array's *type*.  That was kind of the opposite extreme - the size and shape were kept track of in the type system, but was actually pretty draconian to use in practice.  So writing a function to sum the floats in two different arrays of two different lengths was impractical.

Comment: But how could it know where a[x][y] exists if it just knows the number of columns but not the number of rows?

Comment: In all but the last dimension, you need to multiply by the number of values on that axis.  The last value (not the size, but the offset) is merely added, not multiplied by.  Consider a + x * num_columns + y.  num_rows needn't come into the equation unless you have bounds checking turned on.